# Substituting non-existent member with existing one in date range clause of MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have an MDX query that retrieves data from an SSAS 2005 cube:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Record Count] } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE { [Dimension].[Date].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[1]:[Dimension].[Date].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[10] }
```

This normally works well.  However, when there are no records on 2012-01-01, it appears that a NULL value is substituted in and the query ignores that date range start parameter.

How can I check to see whether that dimension member exists and use another date (2012-01-02) in that range clause if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this did it:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Record Count] } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE { IIF([Dimension].[Date].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[1] IS NULL, [Dimension].[Date].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[2], [Dimension].[Date].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[1]):[Dimension].[Date].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[10] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does a subcube query have the same issue?

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Record Count] } ON COLUMNS
FROM 
(SELECT [Dimension].[Date].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[1]:[Dimension].[Date].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[10]
ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube])
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like that runs into the same issue.  Executing that subcube query alone also appears to highlight the same problem - because there are no records on 2012-01-01, the query substitutes in a NULL for that member which causes it to ignore the date range start clause and returns all records that exist in the cube up until 2012-01-10.